# Which is right? believe or believe in

Tags: word-usage

You should **believe** me

You should **believe in** me

Both of two are  natural ? 
When i intend to say that you should  trust me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were asking someone to believe a statement I had made, I would say: "Believe me." If I were asking someone to put their trust in me as a person (my character, my reliability, my ability), I would say "believe in me". Both make sense. Both statements are asking for trust with the distinctions that I have indicated.

Answer (score 0):

To say

> You should believe me.

is to say that you should accept what i say as truth. To say:

> You should believe in me.

is to say that you should have faith in me, accept my value as a person, accept my actions as correct.

The meanings are quite different.